# Check tryCatch multiple times

Tags: r

I have script which sends emails to multiple people. Sometimes it returns error so I want to try it 3 more times. If it's not successful in 3 attempts then returns error message. As of now I am using `tryCatch()` which returns message when error occurs in first attempt and skips to next recipient.

```
 tryCatch({ CODE HERE }, error=function(e){
                  print("Email not sent")
        })
```

**CODE**

```
library(blastula)

create_smtp_creds_file(
 file = "gmail_secret",
 user = "sender@email.com",
 provider = "gmail"
 )

email <- prepare_test_message()

email %>%
  smtp_send(
    from = "sender@email.com",
    to = "recipient@email.com",
    credentials = creds_file(
      "gmail_secret")
  )
```

Comment: Have you considered a while statement that repeats up to 3 times?

Comment: No, any example for while on this problem would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a while loop:

```
fails <- 0
success <- FALSE

while (fails < 3 && !success) {
  a <- tryCatch(
    smtp_send(email, 
              from = "sender@email.com", 
              to = "recipient@email.com",
              credentials = creds_file("gmail_secret")
    ), error = function(e) e)
  if (!inherits(a, "simpleError")) {
    success <- TRUE
  } else {
    fails <- fails + 1
  }
}

if (!success) print("Email not sent")
```

Comment: @BenBolker Ah, it seems that I did not properly edit my final code. I'm going to delete it for a second to figure out where it went wrong. But yes, the current version is incorrect.

Comment: @BenBolker This was the code I intended to post, my bad. So, if there is an error, `a` will inherit class `simpleError`, and then `fails <- fails + 1`.

Comment: Seems OK now. I was a little worried about scoping, but I think unnecessarily.

Comment: Thank you. Can i add Sys.sleep(2) after fails <- fails + 1 before checking in each iteration?

Comment: @UjjawalBhandari Yep, that should be fine. You can also mess around with it by swapping out the `smtp_send` call with `1 + "e"` (since that will yield an error).